# Typing input/output of parsed URLSearchParams

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I've got a React hook that will write an object's contents into the URL search parameters, and accepts a "decoder" argument for each key to parse/cast a param from a string back to its original type.
The hook accepts a single type param describing the object's shape and is overall thoroughly typed with one hole: I can't get it to infer the decoder return value from the type param.

Is it possible for the hook to use a single type param for both the input object and the decoder return values?

Currently:

1. TS complains if a key in T does not have a decoder
2. TS complains if a decoder does not have a corresponding key in T
3. TS complains if the setQueryParams argument does not match T

However the decoder return value is ignored and all queryParam values are typed based on T.

```
export function useTypedQueryParams<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  paramDecoders: Record<keyof T, (value?: string) => T[keyof T]>,
): [T, (params: T) => void] {
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();

  const paramDecodersRef = useRef(paramDecoders);

  const baseQueryParams = useMemo(
    () =>
      Object.entries(queryString.parse(search)).reduce(
        (acc, [key, value]) =>
          !paramDecodersRef.current[key as keyof T]
            ? {
                ...acc,
                [key]: value,
              }
            : acc,
        {},
      ),
    [search],
  );

  const parsed: T = useMemo(() => {
    const parsedQuery: Record<string, string> = queryString.parse(search);

    return Object.keys(paramDecodersRef.current).reduce(
      (parsedParams, paramKey) => {
        const decoder = paramDecodersRef.current[paramKey];
        const value = parsedQuery[paramKey as string];

        return {
          ...parsedParams,
          [paramKey]: decoder ? decoder(value) : value,
        };
      },
      {} as T,
    );
  }, [search]);

  const setQueryParams = useCallback(
    (updatedParams: T) => {
      const newQueryString = queryString.stringify({
        ...baseQueryParams,
        ...updatedParams,
      });

      history.push({
        search: `?${newQueryString}`,
      });
    },
    [history, baseQueryParams],
  );

  return [parsed, setQueryParams];
}
```

Usage:

```
const [queryParams, setQueryParams] = useTypedQueryParams<{
  foo: string | null;
  bar: number | null;
}>({
  foo: (value?: string) => value || null,

  // TODO: TS won't catch that bar can be a string instead of a number
  bar: (value?: string) => value || null,
});
```

Comment: `T[keyof T]` is the union of the value types for _all_ keys, in this case `string | number | null`. Given you want the value types for _specific_ keys, try a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) - https://tsplay.dev/WJAG5m.

Comment: Very nice @jonrsharpe. That absolutely got me there. Posting my own answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came from @jonrsharpe's suggestion/comment:

> T[keyof T] is the union of the value types for all keys, in this case string | number | null. Given you want the value types for specific keys, try a mapped type - tsplay.dev/WJAG5m.

**Implementation**

```
type ParamDecoders<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: (value?: string) => T[K];
};


export function useTypedQueryParams<T>(
  paramDecoders: ParamDecoders<T>,
): [T, (params: T) => void] {...}
```